# Searchkick::ImportError while trying to reindex

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

I am trying to implement elasticsearch on rails app using `searchkick` as the wrapper.

I have a model called **Article** which hash `uuid` and `title` as columns

I have added `searchkick` in Article model.

Now when I am trying to run `Model.reindex` like stated in the searchkick documentation as follows:

`Article.reindex` from rails console

I am getting the following error

`{"count":93,"exception":["Searchkick::ImportError","{\"type\"=\u003e\"mapper_parsing_exception\", \"reason\"=\u003e\"failed to find type parsed [keyword] for [title]\"} on item with id '003566ec-3952-4d26-ba99-f568367f174b'"],"exception_object":"{\"type\"=\u003e\"mapper_parsing_exception\", \"reason\"=\u003e\"failed to find type parsed [keyword] for [title]\"} on item with id '003566ec-3952-4d26-ba99-f568367f174b'"}
Searchkick::ImportError: {"type"=>"mapper_parsing_exception", "reason"=>"failed to find type parsed [keyword] for [title]"} on item with id '003566ec-3952-4d26-ba99-f568367f174b'`

And yes elasticsearch service is up and running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your are using a 2.X Elasticsearch Cluster when your version of searchKick expecte a 5.X+ ( where type text and keyword were introduced )

Did you check this from [searchkick readme](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#getting-started)

> The latest version works with Elasticsearch 5 and 6. For Elasticsearch
>   2, use version 2.5.0 and this readme.